# Flutter convert camera image to image

Tags: flutter, image

Iam trying to convert camera image to image using image library. I got error on the line img.data![index] = hexFF | (b << 16) | (g << 8) | r. The error show is : The operator '[]=' isn't defined for the type 'ImageData'. Try defining the operator '[]='.

Here is the function.

```
imglib.Image _convertCameraImage(CameraImage image, CameraLensDirection _dir) {
    int width = image.width;
    int height = image.height;
    var img = imglib.Image(width: width, height: height);

    final int uvyButtonStride = image.planes[1].bytesPerRow;
    final int uvPixelStride = image.planes[1].bytesPerPixel!;
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        final int uvIndex = uvPixelStride * (x / 2).floor() + uvyButtonStride * (y / 2).floor();
        final int index = y * width + x;
        final yp = image.planes[0].bytes[index];
        final up = image.planes[1].bytes[uvIndex];
        final vp = image.planes[2].bytes[uvIndex];
        int r = (yp + vp * 1436 / 1024 - 179).round().clamp(0, 255);
        int g = (yp - up * 46549 / 131072 + 44 - vp * 93604 / 131072 + 91)
            .round()
            .clamp(0, 255);
        int b = (yp + up * 1814 / 1024 - 227).round().clamp(0, 255);
        img.data![index] = hexFF | (b << 16) | (g << 8) | r; ///error on this line
      }
    }
    var img1 = (_dir == CameraLensDirection.front) ? imglib.copyRotate(img, angle: -90) 
        : imglib.copyRotate(img, angle: 90);
    return img1;
}
```

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: i am using image version 4.0.15

Comment: What is the purpose passing by  `controller.startImageStream(...`  with  `CameraImage` rather than `XFile` by `controller.takePicture(..` which is more flexible by allowing to do what you want in 3/4 lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/ImageData-class.html), you will see that ImageData does not support what you are trying to do.

You can use the iterator method to iterate over the elements of the ImageData or elementAt or forEach.